# Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got this error

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given,

when I tried add `array[]` in my View using select form. But when I removed it I didn't get any error. I'm just trying to input a multiple value in my select list. Do I need to use `foreach` for this?

**View**

```
<div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('approver') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

    <label for = "approver" class = "control-label">Approver:</label>

    <select name = "approver[]" multiple class = "form-control select2-multi">

        @foreach ($approver as $list)
            <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>

    @if ($errors->has('approver'))
        <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('approver') }}</span>
    @endif

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function getDocuments()
{
   $approver = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

   return view ('document.create')->with('approver', $approver);
}

public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)+/|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'recipient' => 'required',
        'approver' => 'required',
    ]);     


    $document = new Document();
    $approve = new Approve();
    $user = Auth::user();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category;
    $approve->approver_id = $request->approver;

    $approve->save();

    $document->save();

    $document->sentToApprovers()->sync([$approve->id],false);

}
```

**Update**

I die and dump the `$approver` variable and gives a array of value.

[image: SC]

Also die and dump the `$request` As you can see here I input the id of **4** and **5** in my select list.

[image: SC]

Comment: Please show the value of `$approver` from your foreach in the view.

Comment: @JaredEitnier I updated my post. `$approver` is a variable where I passed this into my view please see.

Comment: Ok so is the issue occurring in your view or when you try to save your models?

Comment: @JaredEitnier Yes exactly this issue is occurring when I added a `[]` in my select form.

Comment: What is the actual data dump (`dd`) of `$approver`? I suspect something is going wrong there as I cannot reproduce this issue locally using your code.

Comment: @JaredEitnier I updated my post please see. I also `dd` the `$request`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, your issue is that you're trying to save an array as a singular value where you need to iterate over the approvers instead.

Change your controller logic around to this:

```
foreach ($request->approver as $approver) {
    $approve              = new Approve();
    $approve->approver_id = $approver;
    $approve->save();

    $document->sentToApprovers()->sync([$approve->id],false);
}
```

Comment: This works. But I have a issue when I tried to insert a two value from select form. It only inserts the last selected? What I did I choose `4` and `5` but `5` was only inserted.

Comment: Sure, so just instantiate a new `Approve` model inside the loop then instead of outside.

Comment: Thanks for solving my issue. Why It always get the last selected? Why do I need to create a new instance?

Comment: Look at your original code. You only declare one instead of `Approve`. Then you iterate over all the `$request->approver`s and save the `Approve` model each iteration. The value of `approver_id` is overwritten each time on the original model unless you create a new model.

Comment: Oh I see that's you included this in foreach loop :)

Answer (score 15):

In my case i wanted to insert bulk data, therefore i got the error.
Then i used the

`User::insert($arrayData)`

and i'm done.

Answer (score 2):

It can also happen when you try to save an array to a JSON field without first casting the field:  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I overwrote the constructor in a model. If you do so, make sure to pass the arguments array:

```
  public function __construct(array $attributes = [], $something_else)
  {
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    //...
    $this->something_else = $something_else;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i not mention the name in :-

```
$request->input();
```

so i just change with

```
$request->input("name");
```

then its works