# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, laravel

It clear shown that $file_ids is array type but still getting this error, and I used different function to know the data type of variable like gettype() it also return array.please help me to get rid from this headache.
Thanks in advance.

```
public function getFilesForLink(Request $request)
{
 $file_ids = array();
    $ids = $request->input('selected_file');
    if (count($ids) > 0) {
        foreach ($ids as $id => $value) {
            $file_ids[] = base64_decode($value);
        }
    }
    $link_id = $this->makeDownloadLink($file_ids, $_POST['password']);
    if ($_POST['via'] == 'Email') {
        $files = File::find($file_ids);
        foreach ($files as $name) {
            $files_name[] = $name->name;
        }
        $this->sendEmail($files_name, $link_id, $_POST['recipient'], 
     $_POST['subject'], $_POST['body']);
    }
```

Comment: `$files_id` != `$file_id` though it should still be an array.

Comment: Actually, its $file_ids everywhere not $files_id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957486/grammarparameterize-must-be-of-the-type-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one place you are using `$file_ids` and in others `$files_ids` so make sure you are using same variable.

In addition are you sure you have valid values in `$file_ids` array?

Looking at the comment the problem is:

```
$downloadLink->file_ids = $file_ids;
```

inside `makeDownloadLink` method.

You are doing something like this:

```
if (count($file_ids) > 1) { 
   $downloadLink->file_ids = implode(',', $file_ids); 
} 
$downloadLink->file_ids = $file_ids;
```

and this will fail when `$file_ids` is array. You should probably add `else` here like so:

```
if (count($file_ids) > 1) { 
   $downloadLink->file_ids = implode(',', $file_ids); 
} 
else {
   $downloadLink->file_ids = $file_ids;
}
```

Comment: I'm using $file_ids everywhere but still getting same error.

Comment: And what exactly your `$file_ids` array contain now?

Comment: its contain ids of checked file in the view.

Comment: Yes, 100% sure $file_ids contain valid values.

Comment: This is only guess - but when you change `$link_id = $this->makeDownloadLink($file_ids, $_POST['password']);` for example - into `$link_id = 'sample';` are you still getting the error? Maybe error is for example inside `makeDownloadLink` method

Comment: here is code of makeDownload()
    
   public function makeDownloadLink(array $file_ids, $password)
    {
        $downloadLink = new DownloadLink();
        if (count($file_ids) > 1) {
            $downloadLink->file_ids = implode(',', $file_ids);
        }
        $downloadLink->file_ids = $file_ids;
        $downloadLink->password = $password;
        $downloadLink->save();
        return $downloadLink->id;

    }

Comment: You are not answering questions. Also comments are not place for putting code.

Comment: Yes, I tried $link_id = 'sample';  as you said its not showing error but it not inserting data in db.

Answer (score 0):

check this pieces of code

```
$files = File::get($file_ids);
```

replace `get()` with `find()`

```
$files = File::find($file_ids);
```