# Laravel Store/Insert Array Values to Database Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

my problem here in my code is I cannot store or insert array values in Database MySQL, here is my controller code please help me. thank you. My Code in Controller has no array or any so.. I dont have any clue how to turn it into array.

***Controller***

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'city' => 'required'

    ]); 


   $citi = new City;
   $citi->city = $request->input('city');
   $citi->save();

   return redirect('/lugar')->with('success', 'Data Inserted');
}
```

***View***

```
<td> {{Form::text('city[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control name_list', 'placeholder' => 'Add Country'])}} </td>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: here, see  _Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given _

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674623/argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-database-grammarparameterize-must-be-of-the)

Comment: it is not laravel it is pure php. i dont understand :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't store arrays in MySQL, its different if you compared it with Mongo (NoSQL).

What you can do is, turn that array into a json string. So `json_encode($request->city)` and save it.

Then if you want to modify it's values once retrieved from DB, you can use `json_decode($data->city)` which turns it back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually save this using serialize or json_encode.

Using serialize:

```
$citi->city = serialize($request->input('city'));
```

Using json_encode:

```
$citi->city = json_encode($request->input('city'));
```

then just use **unserialize** and **json_decode** on your blade file.

Comment: how can I unserialized it??

Comment: Arrays are now in my database but they are serialized.. how can I unserialized them?  they have the value of this **a:2:{i:0;s:7:"New York";i:1;s:8:"Chicago";}**

Comment: hey @kapitan, all works fine except for the **a:2:{i:0;s:7:** for this serial code.. can i remove that and change it to normal? help me so i can upvote your answer and marked it as an asnwer ty

Comment: unserialize($myvariable) or json_decode($myvariable)